# CodeIgniter hide post id and only title show in URL

Tags: codeigniter

I am working in Codeigniter and I want to hide ID from URL.

my current URL is:

```
www.localhost/CI/services/1/ac_repair
```

but need this type of URL in codeigniter:

```
www.localhost/CI/services/ac_repair
```

---

View Page Code:

---

```
<?=anchor('services/' . $ser->s_id . '/' . url_title($ser->s_title,'_') ,'View Service');?>
```

---

Controller Code:

---

```
public function services()
    {
        $this->load->model('ServicesModel', 'ser_model');


        $s_id = $this->uri->segment(2, 0);
        if($s_id){

            $get_service = $this->ser_model->get_ser($s_id);
            return $this->load->view('public/detail', compact('get_service') );
        }
        else
        {
            // $services = $this->articles->articles_list( $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3) );
        $get_services['result'] = $this->ser_model->all_services_list();
        // $this->load->view('public/services', ['services'=>$services]);

        $this->load->view('public/services', $get_services);
        }
    }
```

---

Model Code here:

---

```
public function get_ser($id)
    {
        // $q = $this->db
        $q = $this->db->select('*')
                ->from('services')
                ->where( ['s_id' => $id] )
                ->get();
        if ( $q->num_rows() )
            return $q->row();
        return false;
    }
```

but need this type of URL in codeigniter:

```
www.localhost/CI/services/ac_repair
```

Comment: Well you might be able to save it in a session or a cookie and pass it along that way... maybe.

Comment: if `ac_repair` is a unique entry in your database, corresponding to s_id=1, then you can work it out from this relation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this functionality you have to be able to use your title `ac_repair` in place of the `id`. This means the title needs to be marked as `unique` and therefore not contain any duplicates.

The following pseudo-code should give you an idea:

```
function services($url_title = null) {

     if (!is_null($url_title)) {

         // get ser would use title instead of $id
         $this->db->where('title', $url_title);     

     } else {

         // all rows

     }

}
```

Other methods would be "hacky" and I cannot think of any off the top of my head that I would consider usable.

Side note: you should never be returning in a view